# Textarea и Contenteditable - в чем разница? И почему selectionStart, selectionEnd не работают со вторым?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать личный HTML-редактор. С textarea всё работает как надо:
([CodePen-1](https://codepen.io/-BUBU/pen/pGmJGB?editors=1010))
Если ничего не выделено - теги добавляются просто в конце напечатанного текста. А если выделить текст - при клике на кнопку, текст помещается внутри тегов.

```
<button title="division" class="tag" onclick="tag('<div>','</div>');">div</button>
<textarea id="form"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
function tag(a,b){
  var x = document.getElementById('form');
  x.focus();  
      var value = $("#form").val();
      var start=x.selectionStart;
      var end=x.selectionEnd;
      var selected = a + value.substr(start,end-start) + b;
  $("#form").val(  value.substr(0,start) + selected + value.substr(end)  );
}
```

Но внутренности Textarea невозможно покрасить или как-то выделить, поэтому есть необходимость сделать редактируемый div, в котором уже можно выделять ключевые слова или теги. Но selectionStart и selectionEnd не работают тут ([CodePen-2](https://codepen.io/-BUBU/pen/ErzVWZ?editors=1010)):

```
<button title="division" class="tag" onclick="tag('<div>','</div>');">div</button>
<div id="form" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

JS:

```
function tag(a,b){
         var x = document.getElementById('form');
             var value = $("#form").text();
             var start = x.selectionStart;
             var end = x.selectionEnd;
                 var selected = a + value.substr(start,end-start) + b;
   $('#form').text(  value.substr(0,start) + selected + value.substr(end)  );
   x.focus();
}
```

Метод тыка не сработал и не понятно, что делаю не так. Видимо нужно просто знать...

Comment: _Textarea и Contenteditable - в чем разница?_ - в том, что это разные элементы, один текстовое поле, второй - нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свойства `selectionStart` и `selectionEnd` объявлены непосредственно в элементах [`HTMLTextAreaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) и [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Так как в случае `contenteditable` элементом является `div` - эти свойства у него отсутствуют.

Для получения выделенного текста можно воспользоваться функцией [`getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

```js
function tag(a, b) {
  var x = document.getElementById('form');
  var value = $("#form").text();
  var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var start = selection.startOffset;
  var end = selection.endOffset;
  var selected = a + value.substr(start, end - start) + b;
  $('#form').text(value.substr(0, start) + selected + value.substr(end));
  x.focus();
}
```

```css
.tag {
  width: 90px;
  border: 3px solid #800;
  color: #800;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#form {
  width: 800px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(255, 222, 159);
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #800
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button title="division" class="tag" onclick="tag('<div>','</div>');">div</button>
<br>
<div id="form" contenteditable="true"></div>
```