# Как изменить выделенный текст при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал вот такой маленький пример:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', changeFontColor);
function changeFontColor() {
  document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "green");
}

div.addEventListener('keydown', setDefaultFontColor);
function setDefaultFontColor() {
  document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "red");
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem, ipsum dolor</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Так как тема для меня новая, мне совсем непонятно, это удачный пример или нет (сомнения с событием `keydown`)?
Ещё заметил, что если в `setDefaultFontColor` цвет меняется на такой же, как и в css, то новый текст не оборачивается в тег `<font></font>`... что мне собственно и нужно, но непонятно почему...это какие-то оптимизации со стороны браузера?

Потом стало интересно, как это сделать "вручную", написал вот такое:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', changeText);

function changeText() {
  var selected = window.getSelection().toString();
  var currentText = div.innerHTML;
  currentText = currentText.replace(new RegExp(selected, 'g'), `<span>${selected}</span>`);

  div.innerHTML = currentText;
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem, ipsum dolor</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

но теперь новая проблема: как "выйти" из тега `span` после изменения цвета и продолжить писать в `div` ?

Comment: С "выходом из span" - Кажется никак. Но по идее можно написать заковыристый код, который перед вводом каждого символа будет проверять - не находится ли он на последнем месте внутри очередного span... и вынести символ за его рамки.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал на данный момент вот так:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', changeText);

function changeText() {
  var selected = window.getSelection().toString().replace(/[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9-\s]/g, "");
  if (selected.length <= 1) return;

  var currentText = div.innerHTML;
  var newText = currentText.replace(new RegExp(selected, 'g'), `<span>${selected}</span>`);

  div.innerHTML = newText;
}

div.addEventListener('keypress', appendChar);

function appendChar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var char;
  var key = e.keyCode;

  switch (key) {
    case 32:
      char = '&nbsp;';
      break;
    case 13:
      char = '\n'; // ?????????????
      break;
    default:
      char = String.fromCharCode(key);
  }

  document.execCommand("insertHTML", null, char);
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem, ipsum dolor</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Может кому-нибудь пригодится.

Но это какой-то мега-костыль и c переносом строки я так и не разобрался.

А, и если вам нужно изменять только выбранное слово, а не выбранное + все его копии, то вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947505/355286

Comment: `<br>` — перенос строки в HTML. contentEditable отличается от textrea) Если в процессе посмотреть его код на странице - оказывается у него каждая строка завернута в отдельный div)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME так что ли сделать `char = '<div><br></div>'`? Ну тогда опять все ломается и записывается не в конец строки а внутрь этого дива с бр'кой

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME хотя, если ввести что-нибудь и только потом нажать `enter` то все отлично.